# Calculating next day's date for special cases of end of month dates

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I'm working on a script that takes a date in the format YYYMMDD as an input:

```
#!/bin/bash
check_dir () {
  d1=$2
  d2=$((d1+1))
  f1=`mktemp`
  f2=`mktemp`
  touch -d $d1 $f1
  touch -d $d2 $f2
  n=$(find $1 -mindepth 1 \( -name "*$d1*" \) -o \( -newer $f1 ! -newer $f2 \) | wc -l)
  if [ $n != $3 ]; then echo $1 "=" $n ; fi
  rm -f $f1 $f2
}
```

In this script `d2=$((d1+1))` calculates the next day's date from the date provide i.e., d1. But, what if the date is 20151231, then it will not be able to handle this situation. Could anyone please help me how to handle this exception?

gdate does not work on my platform!!

Answer (score 1):

With the `date` version from GNU coreutils (i.e. used in Linux):

```
$ date -d '20151231 +1 day' +'%Y%m%d'
20160101
```

Comment: So, d2=$((d1+1)) will become d2=$ date -d '$d1 +1 day' +'%Y%m%d' ?

Comment: The single quotes in the example weren't too good, because single quotes retain the literal string '$d1'... And you need to brace the date command: `d2=$(date -d "$d1 +1 day" +'%Y%m%d')`

Comment: Please tell me how to add it to the script